# UIDeviceRGBColor isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uipickerview

Can someone tell me what exactly is that about?
I have table and inside the tableCell I have a pickerview and some textfields in other cells.
When i'm scrolling the table up and down 8-10 times app crashes and gives me this error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIDeviceRGBColor isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5834850'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: it is trying to call -isEqualToString: on an instance of UIDeviceRGBColor, which is doesn't respond to it.

Long answer: you're either asking for the wrong object at some point, or quite possibly trying to access an object that has been released, but who's pointer has not been set to nil. Sometimes when this happens you'll get a straight crash as the memory in the new location isn't a proper object. Sometimes a new object takes its place. The best way to find out is to turn on Zombies.

This is a good overview of how to use Zombies: http://iosdevelopertips.com/debugging/tracking-down-exc_bad_access-errors-with-nszombieenabled.html

You may start seeing messages saying "-[NSCFString isEqualToString:] message sent to deallocated instance". If so then this is a memory management problem and you need to double check your retains & releases. If you don't get this message then you are likely calling the wrong method and so getting the wrong object back.